# Sorting in map on the basis of order of numeric key

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `Map<String,Map<Integer,String>>`

Sample data in this map

```
("aa" , ((3, "xx"),(5, "yy"),(1,"zz")))

("bb" , (5, "zz"))
```

Here Integer key of the inner map lies between 1 to 5. It is basically a *priority number*.

Now I need to fetch value for some key (say `aa`). It should return values from the inner map with the highest priority number (key).

In above example , `yy` should be returned.

*Note: order of insertion of data in map has nothing to do with order of inner map's key.*

What should I do -

- Use sorted inner map on the basis of key while populating map data?
- Iterate over the map with the highest priority value (*5 in this case*) to lowest (*1 in this case*)?
- Sort inner map in ascending order of key and get the last value?

Comment: Won't the second `aa` override the first value? I guess it should be `Map<String,List<Map<Integer,String>>>`

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I think the second `aa` was just referring to adding another value to the inner map.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg i updated question

Comment: @4castle. Right. wasn't clear form the question. thanks

Comment: @4castle you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options 2 & 3 are less efficient, because you will have to sort/iterate every time you poll for a value.

You can implement option #1 with a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and all the sorting will be handled for you as elements are added. Then use [`TreeMap#lastEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--) to get the entry with the highest key value.

Using some Java 8 features:

```
Map<String,TreeMap<Integer,String>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();

public void insert(String outerKey, Integer innerKey, String innerValue) {
    outerMap.computeIfAbsent(outerKey, k -> new TreeMap<>())
        .put(innerKey, innerValue);
}

public String pollHighest(String outerKey) {
    return Optional.of(outerKey)
        .map(outerMap::get)
        .map(TreeMap::lastEntry)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: thanks for sample code using Java8 But  I am using Java 7. Although I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 will have `O(n)` complexity in worst case.

Option #3 will need sorting at each and every step. That would be `O(n)` in worst case, if you insert elements one by one using Insertion sort algorithm.

For internal map, you can use [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). It will keep the data sorted for you. `TreeMap` guarantees `log(n)` time complexity for operations. For your case, a priority queue (made using max heap) can also be used.

Comment: One thing to note when using a priority queue though, is that it will allow duplicates.

Comment: Yes, Priority Queue will allow duplicates. But, I don't think it will affect above requirement. The duplicate values can be eliminated by the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If no other operations are done on this map, them it is better to go with option#1 which builds the map as per the requirement. No need of further iterations over it.

I suggest to use treeMap for the innerMap on the basis of key.

Comment: Does this add any more than my answer? If you agree with an existing answer, just upvote.